# How can i get the paypal jar file for android?

Tags: android, sdk, jar, paypal, integration

I have searched in https://developer.paypal.com/ can anybody help me to find this
and how to integrate the paypal with android please suggest me any usefull links

I tied with this link

http://androiddevelopement.blogspot.in/2011/04/adding-paypal-payment-in-android.html

```
<activity android:name="com.paypal.android.MEP.PayPalActivity"
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13120186/1168654

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the jar file from provided link and add it in to libs folder - https://www.x.com/sites/default/files/PayPal_MECL_1.0_Android-Developer-Package_0.zip

Answer (score 0):

You can download the jar file from this link..
[Jar file for PAYPAL](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/App/Download_Free_code_PayPal_Android_SDK.htm)